# Formula for average entries per day

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a very simple sheet with dates in column A and product names in column B. I just need to know how many sales I make on average per day.

```
Sales:
01/01/2018  PRODUCT A
01/01/2018  PRODUCT A
01/02/2018  PRODUCT A
01/02/2018  PRODUCT B
```

Average sales per day: `2`

So I don't care what product it is. Just how many sales per day on average.

Comment: Be careful with that link @Nic3500; you could break the internet.

Comment: Create a pivot table of Count of Product against Date, then average the counts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `counta(a2:a5)` to get the count of items in a range (adjust your range to suit of course).

You can use the *array* formula `sum(1/countif(a2:a5,a2:a5))` to get the count of *unique* items in a range. The way to get an array formula is to enter it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd> rather than just <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (it will show up in the formula bar with `{braces}`).

It should then be a simple matter of dividing the former by the latter to get the average items per unique item (sales per day and, again, this should be an *array* formula):

```
=counta(a2:a5)/sum(1/countif(a2:a5,a2:a5))
```

The only tricky bit there is the `countif` formula. The expression `countif(range,value)` will give you a count of all items in the `range` that match the `value`.

By making the value the same as the range, it counts (for each item in the range) the number of times an item appears.

So, if your range contains `a,a,a,a,b,b,c`, you'll get the array `(4,4,4,4,2,2,1)`. Doing the sum of the reciprocals of those values for each cell in the range gives:

```
(1/4 + 1/4 + 1/4 + 1/4) + (1/2 + 1/2) + (1/1)
```

which is basically a sneaky way of counting the unique items.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming dates are entered as real Date (and not just text that only *looks* like dates), use this

```
=COUNT(A:A)/SUM(--(FREQUENCY(A:A,A:A)>0))
```

(Frequency formula sourced from [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-numeric-values-in-a-range) )